# Controlling the visibility of tabs in a subform

Tags: vba, ms-access

Currently implementing toggle buttons that controls the visibility of tabs in a subform. When opening the subform on its own, the toggle buttons work, however when I am on the main form, the toggle buttons don't work anymore.

```
Private Sub Toggle53_Click()
If Me.Toggle53.Value = True Then 
   Me.IDD.Visible = True 
   Me.IDS.Visible = True 
  Else 
   Me.IDD.Visible = False
   Me.IDS.Visible = False 
End If
```

I also tried implementing this code in
`Private Sub Form_Current()`
for the subform's current event,  but it doesn't work either.

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Don't know the structure of your forms, but to hide a tab using a toggle button, you need to reference the tab by index as shown below. Obviously, if the tab control is located in a subform control, you will need to change the reference to it.

```
Private Sub Toggle1_Click()
    TabCtl.Pages(0).Visible = Toggle1.Value
End Sub
```

If the tab control is located in a subform control:

```
Private Sub Toggle1_Click()
    SubformControl.Form.TabCtl.Pages(0).Visible = Toggle1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: not sure if we are on the same page, but the tabs are also within the subform. Meaning to say when I toggle the buttons on jsut the subform as the only form it works, but when i am on the main form with the nested subform, the tab control doesn't work anymore

Comment: If the toggle button and the tab control are on the same form, use the first example. Use the example above and make sure the event is firing.

Answer (score 0):

If all the forms are on the page you could add condittional If on them with booleans to show them, so on toggle click just set everyones boolean to false except the item you want to be visible.
For example create boolean called IDDbool=false, bind it to the subform and change it on click to true to show it.

Also option is to create method on the sub form that controls the tabs and call in that method from the main one.

Comment: Not quite sure if I follow what you are trying to say, can you put in a code example? So that i can help make some sense

Comment: So you are trying to access the tabs on the form2 from form1. If you create a method in form2 that is public with parameter hideitem that represents the number of the tab you want to hide, and in that form create if-else with the number you can switch the boolean that will change the visibility of that tab. In code example
Public Function HideTab(Param1 As Integer)

if(param1==1)
IDDbool=false;
EndIf  
End Function

Now in code you can go:

Call forms("above form").HideTab(1)